# Change the user picture for Git in Xcode

Tags: git, ios7, xcode5, settings

Is there any way to change the Git user picture for Xcode5?

I can change the username and email with command like this:
`xcrun git config --global user.name 'new_user_name'`
`xcrun git config --global user.email 'new@email.com'`

But what about the user picture？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user pictures in Xcode are linked to your Mac Contacts. If the contact has a picture and you associate that contact with a Git committer then Xcode will show it in History. Here's how it works in Xcode 6, try it in Xcode 5:

- in Source Control - History, hover over the name of the committer
- click on that super teeny tiny disclosure triangle
- from the drop down menu, select Add to Contacts
- you can now create a new contact, including a picture, or "Choose existing" and pick a contact
- confirm your choice and the icon shows up in your project

Xcode isn't clever enough to apply the same committer contact to all your projects so you need to repeat this process for each project.

[image]

Comment: Does it work on Xcode 14 ?
Does history move to source control navigator?

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't store committer or author pictures or avatars, so you don't need to set a picture there.

GitHub uses [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) to get an avatar for the email addresses that *are* stored in the commits, and I imagine Xcode is doing the same here. Try changing the gravatar associated with the email address you used and seeing if that does what you want.

Comment: The 'user picture' I said was the picture displayed in `Project history` in `Source Control` of Xcode5.